# Tool for drawing mockup web interfaces

Tags: drawing, mockups

What program was used to draw the picture below?
[image]

Comment: Maybe [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a programming question...but I think is balsamiq: http://balsamiq.com/

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it s made with [balsamic mockup](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups), it's not free btw.

A great source for wireframing tools can be found [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/05/50-free-ui-and-web-design-wireframing-kits-resources-and-source-files/).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/), an OS X app. See http://graffletopia.com/ for stencils (e.g. http://graffletopia.com/stencils/445)